# Run script on solaris start

Tags: node.js, solaris, startup, reboot

When I fired `svcs -a` i got
`legacy_run     11:47:21 lrc:/etc/rc3_d/S99hrms_init_sh`
but when reboot zone that script is not executing.
But it's running properly using `/etc/init.d/hrms_init.sh start`.
I used `ln -s /etc/init.d/hrms_init.sh /etc/rc3.d/S99hrms_init.sh`
 to set it in `rc3.d`.
Edited: added script file.

Script

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVER="/root/hrms/app.js"

do_stop()
{
    echo -n $"Stopping $SERVER: "
    pid=`ps -ef | grep "node $SERVER" | grep -v " grep " | awk '{print $2}'`
    kill -9 (ps -ef | grep "node $SERVER" | grep -v " grep " | awk '{print $2}') > /dev/null 2>&1
    RETVAL=$?
}

case "$1" in
    start)
            node /root/hrms/app.js
            RETVAL=$?
            ;;
    stop)
            do_stop
            ;;
    restart)
            do_stop
            do_start
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
            RETVAL=1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Also tried by manifest [link](https://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/Using+manifold).
But that manifest shows online* but not running.

Comment: What are the contents of your script?  Solaris uses `sh` to **source** init scripts - and `sh` is not `bash` despite Linux conflating the two.

Comment: @AndrewHenle updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is executed at boot but fails if the `node` command is not in the default PATH. If that is the case, you need to set the expected PATH in the startup script.

By the way,

```
echo -n $"Stopping $SERVER: "
```

is bogus, should be:

```
printf "Stopping $SERVER: "
```